# OpenType MPlib labels with luatex-plain

Tags: luatex, plain-tex, metapost, luamplib

I am trying to get the `luamplib` to work with the `luatex-plain` -format.

I installed BasicTeX2014, and then did `tlmgr install context`. Then I did `luatex --ini /usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/context/luatex/luatex-plain.tex`, and moved the generated `.fmt` to `~/Library/texlive/2014basic/texmf-var/web2c/luatex`. I already had a soft link in my `~/bin/luatex-plain` to `/usr/texbin/luatex` from last year.

Now, with a TeX document such as

```
\mplibcode
beginfig(1);
label.rt("sup", origin);
endfig;
\endmplibcode

\bye
```

I get `Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).` in the log file, pointing to the expansion of the macro `\MPLIBtextext` as

```
l.4 ...{s}\hbox{u}\hbox{p}}{0}{-2.9448582181895e-05}
```

Surrounding the `sup` with `btex`/`etex` instead of double quotes, I get an error message informing me I should use those only with files, so I assume double quotes is the way to go.

Can you tell if I am doing something wrong here?

Comment: Your example compiles without error on a fresh MacTex installation (ie the whole 2.3G bytes of TL2014), so it looks like BasicTex is missing something else you need.  Did you install luamplib?  Any reason you can't do a full install?

Comment: @Thruston: I think `luamplib` is included via the `luatex-plain` format. I don't have very much disk space, so I'd rather not install 2.3Gb of stuff I won't be doing anything with.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using the following for mplib with OpenType fonts in luatex (no format):

```
\input luaotfload.sty
\input luamplib.sty
%\mplibsetformat{metafun} % optional use of metafun extensions

\mplibcode
beginfig(1);
label.rt(btex sup etex, origin);
label.top("test", origin);
endfig;
\endmplibcode

%%%% Example Using an OpenType font %%%%
\font\bigfont = "[texgyreschola-regular]:mapping=tex-text;script=latn;+tlig" at 20pt
\bigfont

\mplibtextextlabel{enable} % use current font for label text

\mplibcode
beginfig(2);
label.rt("bigtest", origin);
endfig;
\endmplibcode

\bye
```

When trying to use the luatex-plain format, I received the same error as you.  I get the impression that the `.sty` files are the most current way to use mplib and opentype fonts with luatex, though I could be wrong.